# When to use EBS Snapshot vs AMI Image

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having trouble understanding when an EBS Snapshot vs an AMI Image would be optimal.

If for instance, I have an EC2 Instance that contains a LAMP stack, with data in the MySQL database, and some other basic files, would it be sufficient to back this up using an EBS Snapshot or do I need an AMI Image?  I understand the AMI Image will also back up the Operating System.  I am having trouble understanding whether it is necessary to back up the OS to ensure the MySQL data is backed up.

Comment: Besides from the answer(s) - this may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619580/aws-difference-between-a-snapshot-and-ami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So take a snapshot if you only need the base volume taken as a backup. From this you can only create a new volume. This can also be used to migrate a volume from one AZ to another, or to move it to a different region.

Take an AMI for the following reasons:

- Take a snapshot of the instance vs the volume, all volumes will have a snapshot taken.
- To rollout in an auto scaling group as a prebaked image.
- To duplicate a server

For your case (a MySQL data backup) a snapshot is enough as you’d restore this to a volume and attach to a new instance.